# PHP PDO Insert Method

Tags: php, insert, pdo

I'm working on a PHP class method to insert form values into mysql database with PDO. The idea is outlined below but I cannot figure out how to pass in the fourth parameter of the method. Could someone explain how to do this?

Thank you!

```
<?php
class Contact {
   private $DbHost = DB_HOST;
   private $DbName = DB_NAME;
   private $DbUser = DB_USER;
   private $DbPass = DB_PASS;

   public function MySqlDbInsert($DbTableName, $DbColNames, $DbValues, $DbBindParams){
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->DbHost;dbname=$this->DbName",$this->DbUser,$this->DbPass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $DbTableName($DbColNames) VALUES ($DbValues)");
        // i know this is all wrong ----------------
        foreach($DbBindParams as $paramValue){
            $sth->bindParam($paramValue);
        }
        // ----------------------------------------
        $sth->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->ResponseMessage(true, 'Database access FAILED!');
    }
}

$object = new Contact();
$object->MySqlDbInsert(
    'DbTableName',
    'DbColName1, DbColName3, DbColName3',
    ':DbColValue1, :DbColValue2, :DbColValue3',
    // this part is all wrong -------------------
    array(
    ':DbColValue1', $col1, PDO::PARAM_STR,
    ':DbColValue2', $col2, PDO::PARAM_STR,
    ':DbColValue2', $col3, PDO::PARAM_STR
    )
    // ------------------------------------------
);
```

Comment: Accepted codes are highly vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 12, accepted):

for dynamic insert in PDO i use below function.

for use this passed values in array format to function :

```
<?php
class Contact
{
    private $UploadedFiles = '';
    private $DbHost = DB_HOST;
    private $DbName = DB_NAME;
    private $DbUser = DB_USER;
    private $DbPass = DB_PASS;
    private $table;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->table = strtolower(get_class());
    }

    public function insert($values = array())
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->DbHost;dbname=$this->DbName", $this->DbUser, $this->DbPass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

        foreach ($values as $field => $v)
            $ins[] = ':' . $field;

        $ins = implode(',', $ins);
        $fields = implode(',', array_keys($values));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table ($fields) VALUES ($ins)";

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($values as $f => $v)
        {
            $sth->bindValue(':' . $f, $v);
        }
        $sth->execute();
        //return $this->lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

}
```

and use it :

```
$contact = new Contact();
$values = array('col1'=>'value1','col2'=>'value2');
$contact->insert($values);
```

Comment: @Your Common Sense can you explain how this code is vulnerable, all i know is he has used prepared and parametrized statement with charset.

Comment: He doesn't use prepared statements but old-fashioned concatenation.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, then do you have any better ideas of inserting values as Object oriented with PDO.

Comment: @Your Common Sense looks to me like he DOES use prepared statements.
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

Comment: @jsh Nope, a properly prepared PDO statement uses $sth->bindParam() or bindValue() to insert any parameters into the statement, NOT in the string fed to prepare().

Answer (score 4):

I would use an array. Perhaps something like this:

```
public function MySqlDbInsert($DbTableName, $values = array())
{
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO('.....');

        // Specify the tables where you can insert
        $allowedTables = array('table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3');

        // Specify allowed column names
        $allowedColumns = array('age', 'city', 'address');

        if (!in_array($DbTableName, $allowedTables))
            throw new Exception('Invalid Table Given!');

        $columns = array_keys($values);
        foreach ($columns as $c)
        {
            if (!in_array($c, $allowedColumns))
                throw new Exception('The column ' . $c. ' is not allowed');
        }

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $DbTableName;
        $sql .= '(' . implode(',', $columns) . ') ';
        $sql .= 'VALUES (' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')) . ')';

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array_values($values));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->ResponseMessage(true, 'Database access FAILED!');
    }
    catch(Exception $e) { $this->ResponseMessage(true, $e->getMessage()); }
}

$contact->MySqlDbInsert('table_name', array('colname1' => 'value1', 'colname2' => 'value2', 'colname3' => 'value3'));
```

All values will be escaped as "PDO::PARAM_STR", though.

Comment: It is vulnerable only if he lets the user specify the column names or the Table name (and if he does that, than he lacks your nickname).. On the other hand I updated the code, to take care of this Issues.

Comment: @mpratt Nope, a properly prepared PDO statement uses $sth->bindParam() or bindValue() to insert any parameters into the statement, NOT in the string fed to prepare().

Comment: @dotVezz check the code, the only parameters that are being written into the sql statement are the table name and the column names, which are checked against a whitelist. The result is a prepared statement which is later filled in the `$sth->execute()` method which is the same as calling each value as `$sth->bindParam(':name',$value,PDO::PARAM_STR)`. Thats what I meant when I said "All values will be escaped as "PDO::PARAM_STR", though."

Comment: @mpratt Ahh, I totally didn't notice it getting put into `execute()`. My bad on that one. The accepted answer doesn't do this and I wound up assuming yours didn't either.

Answer (score 0):

My `INSERT` function

```
function basicInsertQuery($tableName,$values = array()){

/*
//
USAGE INSERT FUNCTİON
    $values = [
        "column" => $value,               
    ];
    $result =  basicInsertQuery("bulk_operations",$values);
*/

try {
    global $pdo;

    foreach ($values as $field => $v)
        $vals[] = ':' . $field;

    $ins = implode(',', $vals);
    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($values));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($fields) VALUES ($vals)";

    $rows = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($values as $k => $vl)
    {
        $rows->bindValue(':' . $k, $l);
    }
    $result = $rows->execute();
    return $result;
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
   return $th;
}
```

}