# PHP: insert into creates 2 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a table of users.

The table is made like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `a9025688_chat`.`users` (
    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `username` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
    `password` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

The php code I use is this:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="***";
$database_localhost ="***";
$username_localhost ="***";
$password_localhost ="***";

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `a9025688_chat`.`users` (
`id` ,
`username` ,
`password`
) VALUES ( NULL , '$username', '$password'
)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) die ("db access failed");

?>
```

However, when I try to make a user, it creates two of them. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Is this all of the code?

Comment: That's all the php + mysql code.

Comment: There is an SQL injection in your code, which is a serious security problem. [Learn more about it here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do NOT use `mysql_*` functions!

NEVER use values directly from `$_POST` without filtering and preparing.

Use PDO for numerous reasons including security.  For more in-depth information see [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)

Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144302/php-pdo-insert-method) of how to use PDO

There is even an easy to use wrapper class if you need some help getting started: [PDO Wrapper](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/)

Comment: I believe so.  The person needs to ditch their code and start over.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was putting off sorting out security but ill do that first and the problem might just fix itself!

Comment: When I first started coding PHP I started using mysql_* functions and it had me in a ditch and caused all sorts of problems.  When I got away from that it really made things easier.  Give PDO Wrapper a try.  It is a nice abstraction layer for an abstraction layer :)  Not all of the documentation is complete though.  You will need to look at the class internally to see the full power of it.  The basics are easy though.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you inserting a null for ID? That might be what is making it insert two rows. You should never do an insert with passing in null for the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your given code. maybe something repost your data (or refreshing the page) after inserting. check your possible javascripts or your browser add-ons.